# Genetic programming for objective / fitness function determination

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic

I hope this question is appropriate. I'm looking for a solution to an genetic program implementation I have in my mind, but I'm still new to AI and have no clue where / how to solve the problem in mind.

So I recently started experimenting with genetic algorithms (finding the optimal solutions), and afterwards now started looking at genetic programming (finding the optimal program for solutions)... The mutation, crossover etc. on decision trees are relatively straight forward to me, but am still struggling to wrap my head around the implementation of problems.

If a genetic program can find the math function for a set of correlating inputs values to outputs, then by looking at the optimization problem (let's say bin packing problem), how can you use a genetic program to determine the most optimal objective / fitness function for the problem? Because then you "should be" able to use that generated fitness function (from the GP) for implementation on the GA to find the optimal solution to the problem? - in such a manner that your GA will perform more robustly

If I understand this correctly, how will the GP process be feasible? Is it some general used technique, is the approach related to fitness landscape evaluation for optimization problems... or? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I know there's a solution, just don't know where / how to search for it, or what it's referred to...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please specify why this is downvoted? If this is something obvious or irrelevant, please specify why, so that I can go look for it...

Answer (score 0):

> ... [I] am still struggling to wrap my head around the implementation of problems.
>
> ... how can you use a genetic program to determine the most optimal objective / fitness function for the problem?

In [evolutionary algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) (GA, GP in particular) a problem is basically *defined* by a fitness function. In such a context it does not make sense to talk about an automated way of finding the fitness function, because it translates to finding a problem, what doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

If your idea lays in a different plane and you think it still makes sense, please try to clarify it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of answering werediver's comments, and providing more context to the specified problem (which can't be summed up in a comment), I can sort of answer my own question although still seeing the implementation extremely complex for the "average skill level" in evolutionary programming.

Nevertheless, if someone else finds this useful, after reading a whole bunch of journals, it points my thoughts to fitness landscape analysis ([landscapes](https://www.bioinf.uni-leipzig.de/~studla/Publications/PREPRINTS/01-pfs-004.pdf), [Surveying landscape correlation](https://repository.up.ac.za/bitstream/handle/2263/37155/Malan_Survey_2013.pdf;sequence=1) ) as an optimization problem.

I interpret it as implementing a number of fitness landscape techniques, such as Entropy, auto correlation, correlation length, fitness clouds, evolvability etc. ([1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d86e/7231b902d852c0963315818b2471e6591941.pdf), [2](https://www.math.vu.nl/~gusz/papers/2010-Using-entropy.pdf), [3](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4983112/), [4](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6557671/)), where one "should" be able to calculate a number of landscape coefficients and incorporate / utilize them as the fitness function for your GP. The GP therefor basically generates a fitness function for your optimization problem (by means such as symbolic regression) and optimizes it based on the assessed fitness landscape analysis, so to change the objective function.

Because as all literature states, the quality of your fitness function changes your search landscape, and correspondingly influences the performance of optimization algorithms such as GAs and PSOs (quantifying fitness landscapes by means of "ruggedness", "deception" etc.).

Another image which I found quite useful (putting things in perspective), illustrated three defined methodologies for optimization objective functions via fitness landscape analysis as [ref](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00665421v2/document):

[image: Fitness Landscape change via objective function optimization]

From the programming side, the two most popular software libraries which I could find (until thus far), however the implementation complexity of either still unknown is:

- [Paradiseo metaheuristics](http://paradiseo.gforge.inria.fr/), with fitness landscape [ref doc](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00665421v2/document) (C++)
- [HeuristicLab](https://dev.heuristiclab.com/trac.fcgi/), automatic fitness analysis [ref doc](http://research.fh-ooe.at/files/publications/2863_EuroCAST_2011_Pitzer.pdf) (C# / C++)

So if anyone else has some valid info or experience to offer, it'll be very interesting to hear your perspective, but from what I read, this is not at all a "easy or transparent" approach.